# Primorial of a number

Tags: java, primes

Given a number n, the task is to calculate its primorial. Primorial (denoted as Pn#) is product of first n prime numbers. Primorial of a number is similar to factorial of a number. In primorial, not all the natural numbers get multiplied only prime numbers are multiplied to calculate the primorial of a number. It is denoted with P#.

Examples:

```
Input: n = 3
Output: 30 
Priomorial = 2 * 3 * 5 = 30
```

As a side note, factorial is 2 * 3 * 4 * 5

```
Input: n = 5
Output: 2310
Primorial = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11
```

The way I think to solve this problem is:

1. Write a isPrime function to test whether the number is a prime number.
2. Write a fuction(int n) that can print n number of prime,
      e.g. n=3, then print 2,3,5 three prime numbers.
3. Multiply all the prime numbers together.

However, I am stuck into the step two.
Please help me to solve this problem, or if there is any better way, please tell me.

edit:
following is my code, I just go to the step two so far. But when I try to test the countPrime function, the output is 0.

```
public class PrimorialNum {

static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static int countPrime(int k) {
    int count = 0;
    int x=0;
    while (x >= 2) {
        if (isPrime(x)) {
            count++;
        }
        x++; 
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(countPrime(2));

}
```

}

Comment: Well, step 2 is basically all the work - what have you done already?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @luk2302 I edit my post and add my code.

Comment: Now you need to explain exactly how it is not working. "It didn't work" is not a problem description.

Comment: If you're going to post code that doesn't work, it helps to describe _how_ it doesn't work. For instance, does it produce a compile error? Does it throw an exception? Does it produce the wrong output? If so, give examples.

Comment: @JamesWhiteley  I've  edit my post and add my code

Comment: @csmckelvey I edit my post again, does it look better?

Comment: @khelwood Thanks for reminding me! I've edit my post again.

Comment: Looks like the code never goes into the loop because you set X to 0 and then say do something while X is greater than or equal to 2. And since 0 is not greater than or equal to 2 you just return 0 instantly.

Comment: @csmckelvey But when I initialize x =2 and compile, the console box runs and non stop...I guess the code I write in step two is totally wrong, but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: You are setting x to 2 and then incrementing it inside the loop and your code says continue while X is greater than or equal to 2 which would be always. Just stop for a minute and actually read what you wrote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might work for you, did not have the possibility to try it myself right now. If k > 0.

1. isPrime()

   ```
   static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
           if (n % i == 0 && i != n) return false;
       }
   return true;
   }
   ```

2.Just print

```
static void countPrime(int k) {
 int x = 2;
 int primesFound = 0;
 while (primesFound != k) {
  if (isPrime(x)) {
   System.out.print(x);
   primesFound++;
  }
  x++;
 }
}
```

3.Multiply

```
static int countPrime(int k) {
 int count = 2;
 int x = 3;
 int primesFound = 1;
 while (primesFound != k) {
  if (isPrime(x)) {
   count = count * x;
   primesFound++;
  }
  x++;
 }
return count;
}
```

Comment: That is because your isPrime method is not working. I updated with a correct one.

Comment: Limit to multiplying prime on a int in this method seems to be 9 times, if you want to go further you can use a long instead for up to 20. If you want even more you have to look at some other method of multiplying very big numbers.

Comment: Yeah..I just found I observe the true and false statement in my isPrime function few minutes ago... so I delete that comment

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You want all the prime numbers up to a limit `n`.  That just screams [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Set up a sieve running up to your limit `n`, and extract all the prime numbers less than `n` from the sieve.  It is trivial to multiply them together, though in Java you need to be careful of the limits on the sizes of the different integer representations.

I will leave implementation of the Sieve to you as an exercise.

ETA: Correction as per Joseph's comment.  You will need to estimate the size of your sieve by using `n` as input to the [Prime Counting Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

Comment: I can't believe this has not been mentioned anywhere in this post until your answer.... I read the first few sentences of the question and immediately thought of SoE. I was shocked to encounter a primality test as I read further down. This should be the answer without a doubt.  Also, thank you for not spoiling the journey by leaving it as an exercise. I should note that maybe you should change the variable when you say *"numbers up to a limit `n`"* as the OP uses `n` as the number of primes to obtain and not the actual upper limit.

Comment: Hey @rossum, I just reread my first comment and realized that could have been taken the wrong way. What meant was that I can't believe that *the SoE* hasn't been mentioned... anywho, I always enjoy your answers and contributions

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print ("");
    int num = scan.nextInt();
    long primorial = 1, faktor = 1;

    while ( num != 0)
    {
        faktor ++;
        boolean isPrime = true;
        for (int i = 2; i < faktor; i++)
        {
            if (faktor % i==0)
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                    break;
                }
        }
        if (isPrime == true)
        {
            num--;
            primorial *= faktor;
        }
    }
    System.out.print (primorial);
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add a few lines on how your code works, or how it is better than the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Primorial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number who's Primorial is to be found");
        int n= sc.nextInt();
        int i=2,primo=1,count=0,q;
        while(n>0)
        {
            for(q=1;q<=i;q++)//check for prime
            if(i%q==0)
            count++;
            if(count==2)
            {
                primo=primo*i;//multiply if prime
                n--;//decrease n when once multiplied to keep track
            }
            i++;
            count=0
        }
        System.out.println(primo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple for and while loops may also be used

Comment: Note that answers that contain only code are generally considered to be poor quality. It appears that you added some explanation in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443158/primorial-of-a-number/78143333#comment137763870_78143333). I suggest that you [edit] your answer and add the text of the comment to the answer. By the way, I also recommend that you take the [tour] and visit the [help].